# this base64 string is not getting decoded

Tags: c#, .net, base64, system.drawing

I have this image represented as base64 string which I have pasted over here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23343680/
there is an image inside it. I am calling a

```
Convert.FromBase64String
```

and it gives me

```
{"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."}
```

Now I have used this website http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter to paste the same string and it renders the image in the data just fine.
What is it that I am doing wrong here, I need to get a byte[] which I will make the image from but I cant.
thanks.

Comment: what do you feed `Convert.FromBase64String`? Say, how do you generate the string you pass the method as an argument

Answer (score 6):

You have to append `=` until the length is divisible by 4. Only that is a valid base64 string.

This code will do:

```
string s = "yourVeryLongBase64String";

if ((s.Length % 4) > 0)
{
    int diff = 4 - (s.Length % 4);
    s = s.PadRight(s.Length + diff, '=');
}

byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
```

Comment: thanks, this is doing fine. Now there is this one problem, if you look at this https://paste.ubuntu.com/23343796/ and paste it on the chrome browser, it will show you the image, and if you use this code https://paste.ubuntu.com/23343806/ (which I wrote) to save base64 converted byte array image and compare, the image is quite not what it looks in chrome. Can you tell me whats going on. thanks.

Comment: I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: hi, i found a little bug in your code, the line int diff = s.Length % 4;
shud be int diff = 4 - (s.Length % 4);

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "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=";
            byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

Add == at the end of string. it will work. the input you are passing is not valid base64 value